# How to phrase this question to be on topic?

Tags: discussion

Question:
I would like to find out if there is a difference employers sense from a candidate having a technical undergrad degree vs. one who has a business undergrad, but a technical masters degree.

I'm not sure how to phrase this appropriately to be on-topic for this site.

Background:

The reason why is because I'm currently in the latter bucket (getting a double MBA/MS in Software Engineering) and I have undergrad degrees in Administration and Economics.

I'm currently applying for summer internships and have found some firms require computer science/engineering undergrad degrees.  My thought is that my application would be fine, as I've gotten into a Master's program for a technical degree, and that should speak to my technical skills/knowledge --> leading to an interview etc.

I've found that these companies are not interested, and I think it's based on them not making this connection.

Comment: Thank you for coming here and asking first :-)  I very much appreciate seeing people put effort into this sort of thing...

Comment: Been meaning to ask this one myself...

Answer (score 6):

The best question for here that I can see is:

> Here is my situation...insert details here
>
> How can I effectively market myself for Technical Internships?

Alternatively

> What can I do to overcome the bias against a
> business degree(BA) when applying for a internship in a technical
> field?

Either of those questions should do well.

Comment: I'd prefer the question to be more generic, considering my problem involves entry-level jobs with a Master's degree... asking a similar Q seems like it might fall into dupe territory otherwise.

Comment: Internships are similar to entry level but different enough that I would argue against calling them dups

Comment: "How can I best" - _best_ smells value judgement (=> may invite debate), I'd rather phrase this a bit more neutrally, maybe "what do I need to learn to" - or maybe with your "alternative" wording

Comment: @gnat - I reworded it to just qualify as effectively

Comment: yeah wording in [rev 2](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/621/2) feels about right